# Merge tags -> Duplicate tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I recently merged [graphical-techniques] into [data-visualization].  I was expecting this to remove the graphical-techniques tags when the other tag already existed, but instead it added duplicates.

Is there any way to dedupe these tags now, short of going through and deleting them manually?  Also, is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the deduplication process and cleaned up.

Renaming does not actually deduplicate tags; if the rename creates a duplicate tag, the post will have duplicate tags..

Comment: Thanks Jeff!  That right, but wouldn't it make sense that if the tag already exists on the question, that it shouldn't result in a duplicate?  Just a suggestion for the `merge` function...

Answer (score 0):

The [graphical-techniques] tag seems to have gone. Maybe it took a while for the merge to go through.

Comment: yes, but aren't there duplicates of data-visualization on the same questions now?

Comment: Oh, I see. I hadn't noticed. Looks like a bug.