# Merging tags, should we do it? How to do it significance-test/statistical-significance Mathematical-statistics/mathematic

Tags: discussion, tags

The two tags [significance-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/significance-test) and [statistical-significance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistical-significance)
are very similar. The same thing occurs with [Mathematics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) and [mathematical-statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-statistics)

I guess these should be merged. What do you think ? if you think merging is a good idea ? how do we merge ? I would propose to merge the smallest into the biggest.

it seems that there is a "deduplication process" (see the Answer of Jeff Atwood [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/666/merge-tags-duplicate-tags))
Should we run that ?

Comment: I agree with both of your tag merging suggestions.

Comment: I agree too. But perhaps we should merge both of significance-test and statistical-significance into hypothesis-testing (which is larger than either)?

Comment: I think significance-test is also related to goodness of fit test (there is a tag for that) significance-test is a relatively important part of testing and most psychologist (and in medical study) use them as it is related to the question "is there an effect". However, I am not at all in favour of having 1000 tags and I would follow rob's suggestion.

Comment: What about Mathematic and Mathematical statisics ? I would suggest to merge everything into mathematical-statistic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Current tag synonym candidates](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/current-tag-synonym-candidates)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to make a general remark; SE engine has a special place for tags merging suggestions; go to tag page, then click "about »" and go to synonyms tab.

The merge happens if some synonym is voted up enough times or when mod pushes this through.

Comment: Thanks mbq! I've just suggested 'significance-test' as a synonym for 'statistical-significance'.

Comment: @onestop Pushed through.

Comment: @mbq don't you see you have super power.. I cannot propose synoyms I don't have enough rep !

Comment: @robin Well, I stated that this is a general remark -- in some time, much more people will have the required reputation (2.5k).

Comment: @mbq "in some time, much more people will have the required reputation (2.5k)." yes but I have also noticed that the required rep increases with time :).

Comment: @robin Not any more; last change was when we have left beta.

Comment: @mbq thanks I did not notice the correlation between these evolutions