# Current tag synonym candidates

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Please post your tag synonym suggestions as new answers in this thread, one answer per suggestion.  Upvote answers where you believe that the suggested tags should be made synonyms, and downvote answers where you believe the tags should remain separate.  Well upvoted suggestions will be eventually implemented by the moderators (and then the corresponding answers will be deleted).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34658/discussion-on-question-by-gung-current-tag-synonym-candidates).

Answer (score 4):

[survey-sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survey-sampling)  (wiki, 162q)
[polling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling)  (no wiki, 45q)

Comment: We also have [tag:survey] which looks more like [tag:polling] at a quick glance.

Comment: We also have [tag:voting-system] which is distinct and for which I have just proposed wiki info.

Comment: Looking at this again I see we also have [tag:survey-weights] which I would have thought was a proper subset of [tag:survey-sampling]

Comment: @mdewey: I think I will ask this as an independent question, to get more people involved. Seems complicated!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, but perhaps:

[mixed-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-model) (5495) $\leftarrow$ [random-effects-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-effects-model) (1450)

I suppose one can have a model with only random effects and no fixed effects, which would make it different from a mixed model, though I don't think the conceptual distinction is so large that it would merit a separate tag. And I think all the questions I've seen with this tag are about using random effects in mixed models.

Comment: I agree the distinction is not large enough to merit two tags.

Comment: It's worth noting that these have different meanings between statistics & econometrics.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica That's interesting - the distinction is not evident in the tag info. If the distinct econometrics definition is sufficient reason to retain both tags, it may be worth a tag edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a fair bit of overlap between:

[p-value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-value) (2573) and [statistical-significance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistical-significance) (5,774)

And the usage of [hypothesis-testing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hypothesis-testing) (9591) overlaps a fair bit as well, though in principle it does differ more.

Is there a case for merging the first two? And perhaps editing the tag info for the third to make a distinction?

Comment: `ss` vs `ht` has been discussed before. I see a subtle distinction, but that doesn't mean they will be used well by typical askers. `pv` -> `ss` may be a viable merge.

Comment: I'm not sure here ... why is p-values more related to statistical significance than to hypothesis testing? By the way, p-values have their own existence, now, without regard to where they come from ... and some uses of p-values can be seen as descriptive.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen To your first point, Bayesian hypothesis testing exists although I doubt it appears often in questions with that tag. And as for the second, I'd be curious to see if that is a common view. I would have thought statistical significance and p-values would be hard to divorce from each other. To me, they seem much closer to each other than to hypothesis testing (which could itself be made a synonym quite reasonably, I think).

Comment: All reasonable comments, I will think more about this and come back later ... we could also compare posts under the tags and see if there is much sign of difference in use ...

Answer (score 1):

There are now two tags, [pre-post-comparison](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-post-comparison) and [change-scores](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-scores) essentially covering the same topic. I propose we let [pre-post-comparison](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-post-comparison)  be the main one (even if is is newer and less used), as it is the most general one.

Comment: (+1) I recently created `pre-post-comparison` because, as you note, there are several closely related topics (with quite a few threads) that are not covered by the much more specific `change-scores`.

Comment: I've come across questions under the `mixed-model` tag that might be appropriately tagged with `pre-post-comparison` too. But the terms "pre-post" (and variants) don't appear in the body of the question because the OP didn't think about it: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/585780/237901). And here is a simply `regression` example: [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/572725/237901). It maybe challenging to apply the `pre-post-comparison` consistently? Or perhaps I misunderstand its application?

Comment: @dipetkov I frequently add relevant tags that the OP missed or is unaware of (often because they're unaware of the terminology). I also leave a comment suggesting that they look at the top questions in the tag if it's a question that is likely to have been addressed previously.

Comment: To my mind, *change scores* & *pre-post comparisons* are (at least subtly) different things.

Comment: @gung: They are certainly subtly different, I see that change-scores is a subset of pre-post-, and for a long time that tag has been used that way. See its tag wiki

Comment: @gung: I still thinks that for the purpose of organizing posts here, it is better to synonimize. What do you think?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, to me they are at least subtly different.  However, I didn't downvote this suggestion or give a firm thumbs-down.  So if others are going for it, I'm not stopping it.

Answer (score 0):

[feature-scaling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-scaling)  (120 posts, no wiki) must be synonymous to either [normalization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normalization) or [standardization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standardization)  (both with wikis), or both ... ?

Comment: *Scaling* seems more generic. Maybe `[n]` & `[st]` should be grouped under `[fs]`, & we could even create a `[centering]` tag to be a synonym as well?  Dunno what's best here...  We probably don't need 3 tags for this, though.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Is centering the same thing as scaling? I always thought scaling was a specific application of the multiplication function, but centering is a specific application of the addition function. (Leaving aside that multiplication itself is repeated addition. :) Do you have a new insight for me, gung?

Comment: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70555/7290) is my standard answer on the specific use of these terms, @Alexis, but I'm guessing `fs` is a *generic* term.  I think these should be grouped together somehow, but how best to do it is unclear to me.  The best superset name would probably be `linear-transformation`, but that doesn't seem like it would be a good choice for our situation.

Comment: I agree with gung -- `[normalization]` $\to$ `[feature-scaling]` and `[standardization]` $\to$ `[feature-scaling]` seems like the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

multilevel analysis $\iff$ mixed model

Comment: If you agreed with @dipetkov, it would be better to delete this suggestion, & then add another.  It's better not to change the suggestion entirely.