# Let's merge/synonymize `arch` and `garch` tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I suggest merging [arch](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arch) and [garch](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garch) tags, or making [arch](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arch) a synonym of [garch](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garch) (I am not sure how I should formulate this correctly).

- I don't see sufficient conceptual difference between ARCH and GARCH models to maintain both tags.
- GARCH is more general, so I suggest keeping [garch](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garch) as the tag name to remain.
- [arch](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arch) has 41 questions while [garch](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garch) has 292; only **11** questions are tagged with [arch](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arch) without [garch](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garch).
- I have checked the questions tagged [arch](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arch) without [garch](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garch) and I do not see that they would be sufficiently special to deserve a separate tag.

If the community agrees (we will see), how can this be done? It would be nice to get rid of [arch](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arch) in a way that it would not reappear soon thereafter and there would not be a need to raise the question again.

**Edit:** vote [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/current-tag-synonym-candidates/4270#4270) in the thread for suggested synonyms.

Comment: I know *nothing* about either arch or garch, but I see that among the 41 [arch] questions, 30 are tagged with [garch]. So there is only 11 questions tagged with [arch] only. It sounds like a reasonable merge case, so I +1, but again, I know nothing about this subject.

Comment: One can either manually retag all arch to garch (with 41 threads it is a bit annoying but feasible) or make a synonym arch->garch (usually takes a lot of time to implement).

Comment: For people less familiar with these terms, merging `arch` into `garch` is essentially the same kind of proposal as one suggesting merging `autoregressive` into `arma` (both of which currently exist, by the way, as do `moving average` and `arima`)

Comment: @amoeba, retagging will not stop the [tag:arch] tag from being recreated when a new user enters it. So making it a synonym of [tag:garch] is the better option, or not?

Comment: The moderators make tag synonyms, but we have a list of them ([here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1200/7290)) & there doesn't seem to be much enthusiasm for it.

Comment: Vote [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/current-tag-synonym-candidates/4270#4270) in the thread for suggested synonyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARCH was made synonym of GARCH by voting on the synonym proposal.
(This way was preferred over mapping both to `arch-garch` as nobody was able to vote for or even suggest the latter synonyms because nobody has the necessary >=5 rep points in the non-existing `arch-garch` tag. - thanks to @amoeba for the note)
The change took place on January 24, 2017.
The case is closed.

Comment: I will add that this happened via voting and, to the best of my knowledge, this was the first ever tag synonym to be implemented via voting (instead of moderator action). By the way, Richard, did you actively ask people to vote for it?

Comment: Another remark: that was the reason why garch<-arch synonym was preferred over mapping both to arch-garch; nobody was able to vote for or even suggest the latter synonyms because nobody has the necessary >=5 rep points in the non-existing arch-garch tag.

Comment: @amoeba, Yes, I sent out about five invitations to vote (without specifically asking to vote *for* or *against*).

Answer (score 10):

Could `arch-garch` become the replacing tag? The two abbreviations are often present together in lecture titles:

- [ARCH/GARCH Models](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/78)
- [GARCH 101: An Introduction to the Use of ARCH/GARCH models in Applied
  Econometrics](http://www.stern.nyu.edu/rengle/GARCH101.PDF)
- [Glossary to ARCH (GARCH)](http://public.econ.duke.edu/~boller/Papers/glossary_arch.pdf)

This way, the single tag could show up when typing the first letters of either `arch` or `garch`, in the "tag box".

Comment: Why not, sounds good to me. Not sure if this is much better than just `garch`, though, but I see your point.

Comment: Vote [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/current-tag-synonym-candidates/4270#4270) in the thread for suggested synonyms.