# Separate questions for tag proposal/change/removal or using single threads?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, meta

I have a meta-meta question: should we use

1. **single aggregate thread** with one answer per tag (e.g. [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/current-tag-synonym-candidates)), where whole discussion happens in **comments**, or
2. **one question per tag** where the discussion happens in **comments and answers**.

I have a feeling that one-thread-per-tag strategy works better (faster, provokes more discussion) than single-aggregate-thread strategy, but I may be wrong. The bad thing about using one-thread-per-tag strategy is that it produces lots of questions - but is this really a problem with the amount of traffic on Meta?

Comment: Is this choice necessarily a dichotomy? A valid opinion might perhaps be "we use whichever one seems to work best for the circumstances, perhaps sometimes including combining questions after the fact"

Comment: Should meta-meta questions be off topic on meta? Shouldn't we get a meta.meta.stats.stackechange.com?  (sorry, I'll show myself out)

Comment: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/are-half-of-tag-synonyms-questions-duplicative-of-current-tag-synonym-candida

Comment: @AndreSilva I think that question is *horrible* (it has my downvote as the most horrible question on Meta.CV). Personally, I would prefer to discuss this again here and then to close that one as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @amoeba I marked my question as duplicate but if you wish we may reopen it - it starts being meta-meta-meta issue :))

Comment: Let's see if people share my attitude towards that old thread. I do agree with gung's answer though, which basically says that aggregate threads should be used for routine and likely non-controversial suggestions whereas standalone threads should be used for potentially controversial suggestions that might require some discussion.

Comment: @amoeba, no problem having a cleaner post for discussing this issue. Actually, I was trying to link a related question to take advantage of existing answers and debate on the matter.

Comment: Tim, as you closed the Q yourself, then if you want it reopened at certain moment you should probably flag for mod attention and explain the situation.