# Should tags [integral] and [integration] be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are two tags, [integral](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral) and [integration](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration), that seem to be used interchangeably, maybe one should be a synonym of the other?

Comment: (This could probably have been added to our master [tag synonym thread](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/current-tag-synonym-candidates).) Do you have a preference about which is the master tag? `-gral` has 122 threads, whereas `-gration` has 43, of which 6 have both; Both have excerpts, neither really has a full wiki. That suggests to my mind that `-gral` is preferred, but I could see either as just fine.

Comment: @gung I don't care much either, so let's go with the shorter & more popular one then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I notice that `[integral]` has 122 threads, whereas `[integration]` has 43, of which 6 have both. Both tags have excerpts, and neither really has a full wiki. That suggests to my mind that `[integral]` is preferred.

I have made `[integration]` a synonym of `[integral]`, and I merged them.