# Tag [tag:image-segmentation] what is this?

Tags: discussion, tags

Please, can somebody who follows [image-segmentation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-segmentation) or otherwise know what it is, write a tag wiki?

Comment: I'll take a stab at it tonight, unless someone else gets there first.

Comment: @Sycorax: Do you get arond to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the reminder, kjetil. I've added a synopsis.

Comment: Can you please have a look at https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/current-tag-synonym-candidates/6030?noredirect=1#comment20341_6030